# logo not full, backgrond image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a logo with `background:url(/img/logo.png) center center no-repeat;`

This my code :

```css
nav.navigation a.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(/img/logo.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-position-y: -13px;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-left: -3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>" class="logo"></a>
```

and this the result for logo :

[image]

As you see, the circle is not fully on top

How do I fully display the circle?

Comment: please add your HTML as well - we like to see a [mcve] for faster resolution.

Comment: this my HTML for logo sir,  <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>" class="logo"></a>

Comment: is the circle part of the background image? if so just make the dimensions of the logo the same size as the dimensions for the image

Comment: At first glance, you are positioning the `background -13px;`  - try setting it to zero.

Comment: if i set the background:0; position background not on top sir, any solution sir?

Comment: the position is not on top because you are telling it to in the `center center` - change that to `center top` (or `top center` I forget which order)

Comment: same sir, i try to change center top, top center not full on top

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "not full on top" - you have a container that 200px by 40px - what is the size of your image?

Answer (score 1):

There's some information lacking in your question, but I'm going to try to offer help in a generic way to see if you can work it out.

Your circle is cut because you set the `background-position` to `-3px`. Remove that, and it will no longer be cut.

I don't know the specs of your image. If it's 200 x 40, then you'll be fine using `background-size: 100%`. Otherwise, you may want to add `background-image: contain`, to make sure that it will always be displayed fully.

Here's a sample with a red background so you can tell where the div is, and an image that is not 200x40px.

```css
nav.navigation a.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red url(http://placekitten.com/g/350/250) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-left: -3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation"><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>" class="logo"></a></nav>
```

Here's a version with a 200x40 picture. Using `background-size: contain` in this particular case will work exactly as with 100%.

```css
nav.navigation a.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/40) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-left: -3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation"><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>" class="logo"></a></nav>
```

Update: I'm going to make another wild guess and say that the reason your logo is not at the very top is because you need to remove `margin-top: 10px;`. Give it a go and let us know.

Comment: The logo is at the very top of my sample, which is based on your HTML. If it doesn't work in your site, it means that you're not providing us with the full picture. That's why you need to create an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.

I had to remove the margin -3%, and the background -13px

```css
 a.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://imgplaceholder.com/100x20) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  float: left;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `background-position-y: -13px;` because it is not valid,
And for the circle, try to look up if other elements hide the logo picture on the top

```css
a.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="logo"></a>
```

Comment: if i remove the background-position-y: -13px; 
logo not to top sir :(

Comment: If that's the case, there is something about the CSS in your containers that is affecting it. Please provide a [mcve] that includes the container and the full css of the container.